# Programmable interrupt controller(PIC) can hold maximum 64 interrupt vector using master slave protocol. What about the other ones?

Tags: x86-16

I was reading about Programmable Interrupt controller(PIC). In master slave protocol PIC can hold maximum 64 interrupt vectors. But as there is 256 interrupt vectors. So what about these other interrupt vectors. I searched for answer in google but didn't get any. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about the 8259 interrupt controller, it has not been used in a long time.  Replaced by [the APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller), supporting up to 224 interrupt lines.  Not discrete hardware anymore today, now it is done by the chipset in the south bridge.